# Cannot add ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, controller

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, altough could call myself experinced programmer in web forms field.
I'm learning MVC now. Trying to add controller with Entity framework abolities.
Here is below code of model class:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Public Class Users
    Public Property ID() As Integer
    Public Property Login() As String
    Public Property Password() As String
    Public Property Avatar() As Image
    Public Property Country() As Integer
    Public Property City() As Integer
    Public Property Phone() As String
    Public Property Email() As String
    Public Property Registered() As Date
End Class
Public Class StopSaleDBContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Users() As DbSet(Of Users)
End Class
```

When I'm adding controller I got error Unable retrieve metadata from ProjectName.Users Object reference not set to an instance of object.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project and try again.

Comment: I did tried. Nothing. May it concern to strongly typed controllers or not?

Comment: Problem was about that line: Public Property Avatar() As Image How should I change its?